Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only console error
I am getting a console error -
The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only:' contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.

This is my policy -
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'self';

Is this because of a syntax error?
